# Golang App Deployment

Tags: deployment, go

I am about to finish my app and I want to deploy it on a private server. I want to be able to do the following things automatically:

- run the go tests
- package the app
- deploy it in the server
- have the ability to roll back

How do I accomplish this easily for a go app?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm using Fabric (python based) for app deployments, and Chef for server management. The thing is, since Go's artifacts are just one big binary, the deployer doesn't matter much, the build process is more important.

I'm just packing Go binaries as tar.gz's and sending them to the server with Fabric. I've never used Capistrano but from what I've read it looks perfect for deploying Go apps.

Comment: I use Fabric much the same. I have a task that uploads my binary to a temp file, stops the current process, swaps in the new binary over the old and starts it up again. Server configuration/automation is handled by SaltStack. Cap & Fabric are very similar so if I were the OP I'd use what I grok.

Comment: @elithrar I have a symlink from say `/opt/<myservice>.<build_number>` to `/opt/<myservice>`. So deploying is simply relinknig the symlink and restarting, and rollback doesn't need to involve redeployment, just relinking to an older version. Plus a "garbage collector" deletes old versions.

Comment: Thanks @Not_a_Golfer. I restructured the question to explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: @juanpaolo you're mixing two different things - a build/ci system and deploy system. Again, Go doesn't enforce anything special. Personally I'm using Hudson for CI/builds (Go integration is very basic, mainly invoking shell commands), and Fabric for deployments (which is also activated as a job from Hudson).

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I would want it to run the tests before it actually gets deployed. If it fails, then it halts the deployment. Actually, come to think it, it _should_ be doable via Capistrano. But like what you mentioned, since Go doesn't really enforce me to stick with a certain library, I'll probably just do it with Capistrano. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpaolo you should run all unit tests during the build process, and run integration tests right after the deployment is done. so again, both systems should run tests. I've never heard of Capistrano as a CI server, people usually use Jenkins, Travis, Hudson, etc.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'm not gonna use Capistrano for CI. I just want to make running the tests part of the deployment step. So that if one of the tests fails it will halt the deployment process.

Comment: why not stop at the build? or are those indeed integration tests?